# NUXT JS dynamic multiple search query parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Please, I am new to NUXT JS and need help.

I have a search page where the search bar is located in its header component which is shared across pages, and upon submitting, it goes to the search page and the search logic is done in the store `store/search.js`

The issue is that no matter what I search and the parameters;

1. I cannot get the values of the query to show on the browser URL like `search?Q=jump&color=yellow`
2. Since my search logic is in the store, I am confused about how to pass parameters from the URL and searching dynamically like that.

below is my code

search bar component

```
<input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search for a location" @keypress="search">

methods: {
        search(event) {
            const btn = event.key;
            if (btn === "Enter") {
                const search_terms = event.target.value;
                this.$store.dispatch("search/search", search_terms);
                this.$router.push('/search');
            }
        }
    }
```

store
store/search.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    result: []
})
 
export const mutations = {
    searchTerms(state, text) {
        state.searchTerms = text
    },
    searchResult(state, result) {
        state.result = result
    }
}
 
export const actions = {
    search(vuexContext, search_terms) {
        vuexContext.commit('loadingTrue')
        return this.$axios
        .$get('https://help.herokuapp.com/place', { params: 
            {
            search: 'lagos',
            idealfor: ["production"],
            page: 1,
            limit: 12,
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            let searchResult = data.results
            vuexContext.commit('searchResult', searchResult)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
        })
    },
}
 
export const getters = {
    searchResult(state) {
        return state.result
    },
}
```

i would like the search bar to show like
`localhost:3000/search?search=lagos&page=1&limit=12&idealfor=["production"]`

and when the link is sg[shared and also visited the desired result would show.

please how would you go about this in Nuxt and are there resources anyone can recommend that would help me with this.

Comment: @kissu yeah a bit, but I eventually gave up on it for now as I still have some issues, I have marked your answer as it was the best I could get so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating the following action

```js
async moveToGivenPathWithQuery({ _ }, { q = {}, color = {} }) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  await $nuxt.$router.push({ path: 'search', query: { q, color } })
},
```

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="moveToGivenPathWithQuery({ q: 'jump', color: 'yellow' })">
      Go to search
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('search', ['moveToGivenPathWithQuery']),
  },
}
</script>
```

`search.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>Search page</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('query received', this.$route.query)
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can update url's query by using `$router.push` to the same page with query included, it won't refresh the page and only updates the query.

for example:

```
this.$router.push('/search?search=lagos&page=1&limit=12&idealfor=["production"]');
```

you can access query values using `$route.query`.
if you want to show the result when the link is visited, you need to check for `$route.query` in `mounted` cycle and dispatch it to the store to get the results.